# Should I reapply the DataSource property when paging a DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I'm paging a DataGrid, and the `OnPageIndexChanged` method looks like this:

```
    protected void dgSurvey_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgSurvey.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        dgSurvey.DataBind();
    }
```

In that method, do I also need to call `dgSurvey.DataSource` = <<`my data source`>>, or is this one of those things that ViewState should handle, provided it's enabled on the DataGrid?

What's the best practice?

Comment: Does it work, without specifying the DataSource?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using the DataGrid. If you are using the DataGrid properties to handle the paging for you, then you don't have to do anything, DataGrid will know how to query the next result set.

But if you are using a "detached" DataGrid, feeding the data as a List, for example, in every PostBack, then yes, you will have to add the new datasource and call databing.